# Sailthru variable campaign_name in templates:

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi all I have been using sailthru email system with my django based website .
I'd like to insert campaign names into email templates for the purpose of email tracking.

```
www.abc.com/{specific_page}?utm_source=Sailthru&utm_medium=Email&utm_content={**email_campaign_name**}&utm_campaign=abc_Promotion
```

This is not predefined in the variable list on the website, nor can I locate this in the api files. I searched the php api files as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: django variables should be enclosed in `{{ ... }}` (double, not single). is that your actual code?

Comment: no actually it is needed in the url . and Thanks for your critical eye but I am aware of that thing {{ variable }}  :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out {blast.name} or {blast.id} from the [docs](http://getstarted.sailthru.com/developers/zephyr-syntax/zephyr-template-syntax-basics)